# FFMPEG: error while decode UDP and Kill

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, streaming, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

i decode UDP stream using ffmpeg to HLS with this code :

```
ffmpeg -i udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000000 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -hls_time 2 -hls_wrap 5 -f hls /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8
```

UDP stream get from a dvb cart and contain live tv, when i run this code after some minute get a message

```
line 1:  8215 Killed        ffmpeg -i udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000000 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -hls_time 2 -hls_wrap 5 -f hls /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8
```

and decode  stop ...it seem that ffmpeg killed, can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try reducing the size of the fifo.

Comment: if i try to convert rtp stream, either must use fifo_size?

Comment: Not really, it entirely depends on what you want to do. Try removing the fifo for the rtp streams.

Comment: after reducing fifo see a error that : av_interleaved_write_frame() invalid argument ..... do you know how to solve that?

Comment: if it not refer to reduce fifo i ask a new question

Comment: It would be good to put it as a new question

Comment: but if realy refer to fifosize, why sometime it ocured in first 10 minute and somtime it occured in 1 hour?